# How to change android:drawableRight programmatically in Android

Tags: android

```
public class Serchresult extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageView1;
    String Status;
    String Reason;
    TextView status;
    TextView reason;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_serchresult);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Status = intent.getExtras().getString("Status");
        Reason = intent.getExtras().getString("Reason");
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchstatus_imgBack);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        reason = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reason);

        reason.setText(Reason);

        if (reason.equals("ACCEPTED")) {
            // reason.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.accept_icon),null);

            Drawable accepted = getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.accept_icon);
            accepted.setBounds(0, 0, accepted.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    accepted.getIntrinsicHeight());
            reason.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, accepted, null);

        } else if (reason.equals("REJECTED")) {
            // reason.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.reject_icon),null);

            Drawable rejected = getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.reject_icon);
            rejected.setBounds(0, 0, rejected.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    rejected.getIntrinsicHeight());
            reason.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, rejected, null);

        }

        else {
            reason.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
        }
        status.setText(Status.replace("null", ""));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.searchstatus_imgBack) {
            finish();
        }

    }
```

this is my Activity code:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Accepted"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want to change  android:drawableRight Programmatically means when accept condition come from server it image icon should different if reject then image icon should different am unable to do this please where am doing wrong help me

Comment: Use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: I tried its not working Dude

Comment: (reason.equals( "ACCEPTED" )), "reason" is a TextView, your code makes no sense then

Comment: @user2794306 I use it **always**. It works **perfectly**.

Comment: why not working in My code while i have debug it and going on that condition But not image is coming please check my Textview XML

Answer (score 0):

User below code,

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
yourView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);
```

where values of setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds are

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

Comment: please look My XML u ll Understand

Comment: (reason.equals( "ACCEPTED" )), "reason" is a TextView, your code makes no sense then

Comment: http://pastie.org/9724907  check this code i have apply but still image is not changing

Comment: @user2794306 you cannot call .equals() on TextView with the parameter of String

Comment: Exactly! do, reason.gettext().toString().equals(XXXXX)

Comment: @user2794306 use Reason.equals instead of reason.equals